# In SQL Oracle, how can I return two values from the same column that share an identifier in a different column?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, aggregate-functions

The data table looks like this:

| Address | NAME | NAME_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A Street | JOHN | FIRST |
| A Street | SMITH | LAST |
| B Street | JANE | FIRST |
| B Street | DOE | LAST |

I want my results to look like:

| ADDRESS | FULL_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| A STREET | JOHN SMITH |
| B STREET | JANE DOE |

The only way I have been able to make this work is run 2 separate queries and join them in Excel.  Is there a way to do this in one go in SQL?

Comment: Reference the same table twice.

SELECT  
    A.ADDRESS,
    (A.NAME) || (B.NAME) AS FULL_NAME
    
FROM
    DATA_TABLE A
    
    JOIN DATA_TABE B
    ON A.ADDRESS = B.ADDRESS
    AND B.NAME_TYPE = 'LAST'
    
WHERE
    A.NAME_TYPE = 'FIRST'

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation and string concatenation:

```
select address,
    max(case when name_type = 'FIRST' then name end) 
    || ' ' 
    || max(case when name_type = 'LAST' then name end) 
from mytable
group by address
```

This somehow assumes that all addresses do have a first an last name available.

Answer (score 0):

Your current table is a denormalized key value store.  One approach uses aggregation with `LISTAGG()`:

```sql
SELECT ADDRESS,
       LISTAGG(NAME, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME_TYPE) AS FULL_NAME
FROM yourTable
WHERE NAME_TYPE IN ('FIRST', 'LAST')
GROUP BY ADDRESS;
```

Answer (score 0):

`PIVOT` and then concatenate:

```sql
SELECT address,
       first_name || ' ' || last_name AS full_name
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX(name) FOR name_type IN (
    'FIRST' AS first_name,
    'LAST'  AS last_name
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Address, NAME, NAME_TYPE) AS
SELECT 'A Street', 'JOHN',  'FIRST' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A Street', 'SMITH', 'LAST'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B Street', 'JANE',  'FIRST' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B Street', 'DOE',   'LAST'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ADDRESS | FULL_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| A Street | JOHN SMITH |
| B Street | JANE DOE |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lxu_U1wE)

Answer (score 0):

Join the same table twice. Worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Please, no images of code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).